# delete last char in input field if jquery autocomplete is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jquery autocomplete function to pull in data from a database in a text type input.

I managed to have the last character removed automatically if the query returns no data after the first 2 characters. But how can I re-run the query after the character is removed?

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#field").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {  
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "<?php echo URL; ?>/librerie/autocomplete.php",
                    data: { what: "type", term: request.term},
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        response([]);
                    }
                 })
                 .then( function(response) {
                     if (response == "") {
                         $("#field").val( function(index, value) {
                             return value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
                         })
                     }
                 });
             },
             delay: 500,
             minLength: 2
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the entire autocomplete call into a named function that automatically executes. Then, you can have the function call itself recursively when needed.

```
$(function () {
  (function doAutoComplete(){

    $("#field").autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "<?php echo URL; ?>/librerie/autocomplete.php",
          data: { what: "type", term: request.term },
          success: function (data) {
            response(data);
          },
          error: function () {
            response([]);
          }
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response === "") {
              $("#field").val($("#field").val().substr(0, value.length - 1));
              doAutoComplete();  // Call function recursively again
            }
          });
      },
      delay: 500,
      minLength: 2
    });
  })(); // Automatically invoke function
});
```

Comment: I doesn't work... first, the `if (response === "")` is never True; if I change it to `if (response == "")`, it deletes all characters, not only the last one.

Comment: Still doesn't work... :-( well, this isn't a priority, I think I'll move on and I'll retry in the future. Thanks for your help!